# Convert MTS video to OGV (OGG) format via Terminal

Tags: video, file-conversion, encoding

Is there a way to convert MTS video format to OGV? And how could you set desired size of output file or file resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done with ffmpeg. First, install it with vorbis support:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-libvpx --with-theora --with-libogg --with-libvorbis
```

After that, run command:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mts -acodec libvorbis -crf 21 -r 30000/1001 -deinterlace -vpre lossless_medium -y -threads 0 output_file.avi
```